# Qnx-neutrino can't format my partitions with fdisc, process freezes

Tags: formatting, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I'm trying to format my HDD 250Gb in QNX-neutrino OS running on Oracle VM in Windows 10. I mounted my HDD and everything looks fine. I run command

```
fdisk /dev/hd1
```

And create 4 partitions with next sizes:

```
1325, 124684, 17265, 47496 MB
```

After that I run command:

```
mount -e /dev/hd1
```

And when I tried to format created partitions with commands:

```
mkqnx6fs –q –b4096 /dev/hd1t177

mkqnx6fs –q –b4096 /dev/hd1t178

mkqnx6fs –q –b4096 /dev/hd1t179

mkqnx6fs –q –b4096 /dev/hd1t180
```

the process starts and never end. Terminal is just frezees. What can I do to fix it? Or there is another way to format my partitions in this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM Ware didn't suit me, because it counted cylinders incorrectly.

I find the solution. The problem was due to poor contact of the USB cable with my hard drive. I tried changing the usb cable and usb port and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when used VM Oracle after markup my HDD. Then I tried VM Ware and this issue was resolved.